# Drop NA values in an imported xlxs document with R

Tags: r

I have the attached document.  I've imported an xlxs document into R.  I would like to get rid of all rows containing NA.  I've tried the following but it isn't working.

```
# install packages Note# tidyverse installs packages for dplyr and ggplot2
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("readxl")

#open the library
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

setwd("~/Documents/UofL/Data_Science/CECS_635/week_3/")

un <- read_excel("UnitedNations.xlsx")

un1 %>% drop_na(un,)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

its should be working

```
data_set<-na.omit(un)
```

If want to handle NA's to mean or median:

```
na.mean(un, option = "mean")
```

Source:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/imputeTS/versions/2.7/topics/na.mean

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the application to drop the NA values by converting the xlsx file to a csv file. Once the csv was uploaded into R, I was able to omit the NA rows.

```
# to remove the NA values I converted the xlsx file to csv  

    united_nations <- read_csv("UnitedNations.csv", col_names = TRUE)

     # used the na.omit option to remove rows with NA 
united_nations = na.omit(united_nations)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or in a data frame:

```
mydata <- data.frame(c(1,2,NA,3))
mydata <- mydata[complete.cases(mydata),]
```